# On blur triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onblur

I was trying to create an editable table using jQuery.

As a part of it I was showing a text-area `onClick` of a td and on blur of that text-area I was hiding that.

The issue is that the text-area blur is triggered exponentially as I go on clicking other td. The text-area is showing correctly only issue is the abnormal trigger count `onBlur`.

It must be a flow in my design. Please guide me on the right path.

Code

```
var $td = $('td')
$td.on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var $self = $(this);
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var height = $(this).outerHeight();
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    var value = $(this).text();
    $('.input').show().css({
        top: offset.top,
        left: offset.left,
        height: height,
        width: width
    }).val(value).focus().on('blur', function () {
        console.log('triggerd')
        $self.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pax5g/)

Comment: works fine for me in latest Firefox... what exactly is the errant behavior?

Comment: @Derek Check the console after each `td` click you will see an exponential growth in the number of times the `onBlur` is triggered. If I'm clicking one `td` after another it triggers 2 times and then if I click another it triggers 3 times. Its supposed to trigger only once in an 'onBlur'

Comment: The problem is because you're adding that `.on('blur')` event every time you click on any TD. The solution is to change it to `.one('blur')` instead. This way the event handler will trigger only once and then be removed. That way each time you click a TD, it only triggers the blur event once.

Comment: @Derek : Thank you. Let me try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you're adding that `.on('blur')` event every time you click on any TD. The solution is to change it to `.one('blur')` instead. This way the event handler will trigger only once and then be removed. That way each time you click a TD, it only triggers the blur event once

Comment: `.one('blur')` is nice trick and working well for me. up-voted with thanks

Comment: Equivalent solution in vanilla JS ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Use unbind() function to cancel the event and then bind the same event using on() function.

Below code solves your problem.

var $td = $('td')
$td.unbind('click').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var $self = $(this);
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var height = $(this).outerHeight();
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    var value = $(this).text();
    $('.input').show().css({
        top: offset.top,
        left: offset.left,
        height: height,
        width: width
    }).val(value).focus().on('blur', function () {
        console.log('triggerd')
        $self.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```